# Merge vector layers problem with german names (ä, ü, ö...)

Tags: qgis, merge, qgis-processing, saga

When I'm trying to merge (saga merge layers tool) some shape files I get an error log

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 91: ordinal not in
>   range(128) See log for more details

Log:

> Uncaught error while executing algorithm
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 232, in execute
>       self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>     File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithm212.py", line 152, in processAlgorithm
>       filename = dataobjects.exportVectorLayer(layer)
>     File "C:/Users/user/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\tools\dataobjects.py", line 302, in exportVectorLayer
>       unicode(layer.source()).decode('ascii')
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 86: ordinal not in range(128)

I guess its caused by the names of the vector files (Umlaut like ä or ü). In SAGA it works but not in QGis. Is that a known issue?

Comment: That's a python common error that I found when I use italian letters (à ò ù è ì). The author should use unicode conversions. Can you post the log details?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).